# where do addElement method defined zend 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

```
$form = new Zend_Form();
$form->addElement('text', 'fname', array('belongsTo' => 'user'));
```

I need to know where is addElement method defined? I have searched *\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend([\Form])* directory but could not find this method!. If there is no such method then please help me to understand how this above two line work and what are other array conf & parameter of this method.

Edit: thanks Crisp. Actually I am trying to make an input array in zf2 like

```
<input name="val[one]" type="text" />
<input name="val[two]" type="text" />
<input name="val[three]" type="text" />
```

Or at least... like this

```
<input name="val[0]" type="text" />
<input name="val[1]" type="text" />
<input name="val[2]" type="text" />
```

I have found a example with above code and its not working as it is zf1.

Comment: The code snippet you're using is for Zend Framework **1**, maybe start with the documentation for the current version of ZF2 instead -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html

Answer (score 0):

In ZF2, programmatic form creation has changed from ZF1. There is no more addElement function, instead you add an element using $form->add($element);

The basic steps to create a form in ZF2 are:

1. Create a form element
2. Create a form
3. Add element to the form

Create a form element:

```
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Form;

$name = new Element('name');
$name->setLabel('Your name');
$name->setAttributes(array(
    'type'  => 'text'
));

$send = new Element('send');
$send->setValue('Submit');
$send->setAttributes(array(
    'type'  => 'submit'
));
```

Create a form:

```
$form = new Form('contact');
```

Add element to the form:

```
$form->add($name);
$form->add($send);
```

However in ZF2, another way would be to use a Factory to generate the form from an array configuration:

```
use Zend\Form\Factory;

$factory = new Factory();

$form    = $factory->createForm(array(
    'hydrator' => 'Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ArraySerializable',
    'elements' => array(
        array(
            'spec' => array(
                'name' => 'name',
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Your name',
                ),
                'type'  => 'Text',
            )
        ),
        array(
            'spec' => array(
                'name' => 'send',
                'type'  => 'Submit',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'value' => 'Submit',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

The form is then referenced from the view and is rendered using form view helpers.

References:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html
https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/develop/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html
http://akrabat.com/category/zend-framework-2/